# How to make Dynamic URL for Browser and Mobile Application - for Customer Confirmation mail URL which is Dynamic?

Tags: android, firebase

I am using Magento 2 and it gives the ability to take more control of the customer account creation process.

There is a special configuration setting located in

> Admin under Stores → Configuration → Customers → Customer Configuration
>   → Create New Account Options named Require Emails Confirmation
>   (Yes/No)

I am receiving the mail and everything's works fine, But my concern is I have **Mobile Application** too for my Magento project.

And In **email confirmation button** I have URL like this

```
https://<magento.host>/customer/account/confirm/?id=123&key=b686b138f5ec5fe5ff7610b7527a9b4b
```

Now, this URL is directly opens in the the browser even if customer has
   **Installed** the **Application**.

How can I make **Dynamic URL** for this specific functionality, If
user have Installed the application then It automatically opens in
**Mobile Application** and if user doesn't have the application then opens in Browser.

---

Or Any suggestions- how can I use firebase for the same - https://console.firebase.google.com?

Comment: Firebase Dynamic Links do precisely that: they open the application if it's installed, and open the play/app store or browser otherwise. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Comment: Can you please guide how to use it for https://<magento.host>/customer/account/confirm/?id=123&key=b686b138f5ec5fe5ff7610b7527a9b4b


This type of dynamic URL